# How to post on a facebook application user's facebook feed using cURL?

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have made a snake game using javascript and HTML5 Canvas element. It can be found at apps.facebook.com/snaqe_game. I have attained permissions and authorized the app for publish_feed or something using the Facebook Developer Documentation but the problem I am facing is while posting the player's score on his wall.
Please Note:

- I do not have the PHP SDK

---

Please See: apps.facebook.com/mg-copter

Comment: Can you post the exact message?

Answer (score 1):

[Update Facebook News Feed using the Graph API in PHP](http://codecri.me/case/318/update-facebook-news-feed-using-the-graph-api-in-php/)

```
$data = array();
$data['post'] = array(
   'access_token' => $access_token,
   'message' => 'this is the message',
   'picture' => 'http://sudocode.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/developer.facebook.com_banner-150x150.png',
   'link' => 'http://sudocode.net/article/313/how-to-register-a-new-facebook-application/',
   'name' => 'How to Register a New Facebook Application',
   'caption' => 'sudocode | it looks like it works',
   'description' => 'Here are some notes on how to register a new Facebook application.',
   'actions' => '{"name": "Read the Article", "link": "http://sudocode.net/article/313/how-to-register-a-new-facebook-application/"}',
   );
$response = xhttp::fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed", $data);
```

Comment: For any one looking, that page is now http://codecri.me/case/318/update-facebook-news-feed-using-the-graph-api-in-php/